# How can I know how many archived logs are saved?

Tags: apt, archive, logrotate

In `/var/log/apt`, I am seeing:

```
$ /var/log/apt $ ls -l
total 100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3343 Feb 14 22:34 history.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2156 Jan 31 06:03 history.log.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1288 Dec 31 11:14 history.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3232 Nov 27 07:22 history.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18813 Oct 31 07:11 history.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  20475 Feb 14 22:34 term.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   4862 Jan 31 06:03 term.log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   3685 Dec 31 11:14 term.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   9058 Nov 27 07:22 term.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  12452 Oct 31 07:11 term.log.4.gz
```

It looks like `history.log` is being archived once a month.

Because `history.log` and its archives are important to me, I want to know:

- how many archives will be stored before the oldest is deleted?
- where is this information located?
- can I change the settings to increase the number of logs stored? (Going from the file sizes and my usage of `apt-get`, I am not concerned about disk space.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful information is in `/etc/logrotate.d`. To see how logs relating to `apt` are handled, look at `/etc/logrotate.d/apt`. On my system, I see:

```
$ /etc/logrotate.d $ cat apt
/var/log/apt/term.log {
  rotate 12
  monthly
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}

/var/log/apt/history.log {
  rotate 12
  monthly
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

And, according to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/logrotate.8.html, `rotate 12` would mean that logrotate would be run twelve times at monthly intervals before the oldest archive is deleted.

Obviously then, editing `/etc/logrotate.d/apt` to modify `rotate 12` to a desired value is the solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That is all handled by `logrotate`. Read `man lograte`, and look at your `/etc/logrotate.conf`.