# How can I get a log of the updates I installed recently?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates

I want to get a log of the updates I installed in my Ubuntu 18.04 recently (say last month) using `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update`. Is there any way?

Comment: See `/var/log/apt/history.log` and the `*.gz` files therein.

Comment: It shows only this month. What if I want last month (Nov.)?

Comment: Look into the *.gz files. See my answer below.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/175504/how-do-i-get-the-history-of-apt-get-install-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The history of the commands `apt`, `apt-get` and the like is stored
in the directory `/var/log/apt` in the file `history.log`:

```
pduck@host > cd /var/log/apt
pduck@host > ls -l history*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3312 Dez  8 16:10 history.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3863 Mär  2  2018 history.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28259 Feb  2  2018 history.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3994 Nov 29 20:21 history.log.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1618 Nov  2 19:06 history.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   421 Sep 22 14:03 history.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   908 Aug 31 16:06 history.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1654 Jul 29 12:22 history.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2298 Jun 30 18:34 history.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2227 Jun  1  2018 history.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2438 Apr 28  2018 history.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4369 Mär 31  2018 history.log.9.gz
```

The file `history.log` is the *current* logfile. It gets rotated
by the `logrotate` job in `/etc/logrotate.d/apt` once a month and
kept for 12 months:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log {
  rotate 12
  monthly
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

To view logs from previous months look into the `*.N.gz` files,
e.g.:

```
zless /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

(No need to unzip them first, `zless` (and `zgrep`) does this under the hood.)

Answer (score 2):

Another route is to examine `/var/log/dpkg.log` and its archives:

```
zgrep "2018-11.* status installed" /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort -t- -k2 -r
```

Notes:

- This command will also include packages that were already installed on your system but updated in the month of November 2018. Change `2018-11` to whatever other period you wish to examine.
- You can increase the number of archives saved on your system by following https://askubuntu.com/a/421072/248158.